# Filtro externo no ng-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sou novo em usar o AngularJS e o ng-table e estou tendo um pequeno problema.

Quero aprender a criar filtros fora da tabela gerada, mas não encontrei nada a respeito no site deles "http://ng-table.com".

Se fizer diferença, o filtro que quero criar é um filtro do título, mas fora da *tag* "table".

O meu código está funcionando direitinho, mas quero fazer um filtro externo.

**Código JS**

```
TemasCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$resource', 'ngTableParams', '$timeout'];

function TemasCtrl($http, $resource, ngTableParams, $timeout) {

    var temas = this;

    temas.carregarTabela = function () {

        var Api = $resource('/temas');

        temas.loading = true;

        temas.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 10,
            sorting: {
                name: 'asc'
            },
            filter: {}
        }, {
            total: 0,
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                Api.get(params.url(), function (data) {

                    $timeout(function () {

                        params.total(data.total);
                        $defer.resolve(data.itens);

                    }, 500);
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Código HTML**

```
<div class="ui attached segment" ng-init="temas.carregarTabela()">

     <table ng-table="temas.tableParams" show-filter="true" class="ui selectable compact table">
          <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="tema in $data">
                    <td class="ui center aligned collapsing" data-title="'ID'" filter="{ 'id': 'text' }">{{ tema.id }}</td>
                    <td class="ui collapsing" data-title="'Slug'" filter="{ 'slug': 'text' }">{{ tema.slug }}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Título'" filter="{ 'titulo': 'text' }">{{ tema.titulo }}</td>
               </tr>
          </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que isto vai lhe ajudar bastante:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular